# Convert to base64

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically I have a column passwordHash and I want to convert it to base64 inside the database.Is there any way to do that with a sql command or even with a function?
Right now the column is a byte[].
The DB engine is Postgresql.

Comment: Please share the table schema.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has a built in function `select encode('base64 encoded string', 'base64');` and a reversal function `select decode('Q2xlYXJseSBHb29nbGUgaXMgYnJva2Vu', 'base64');`